# Error in my hibernate request

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, orm

Hello i have this HQL request and i have an error when I run it

My function:

```
public ProprietaireInt getProprietaireInt(String codeImmeuble, String annee) {
   //Create connexion
   Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
   ProprietaireInt proprietaireInt = new ProprietaireInt();
   try{
         String query = "SELECT pi.siren,pi.codeSCI,pi.libSocieteInterne,pi.libSocieteNormalise,pi.codeDomainePilotage " +
                        "FROM ImmeubleFisc if" +
                        "JOIN proprietaireInt pi ON if.sirenProprietaire = pi.siren " +
                        "WHERE if.idImmeubleFisc.codeImmeuble = :codeImmeuble " +
                        "AND if.idImmeubleFisc.exerciceFiscal = :annee";
        Query q = null;
        q = session.createQuery(query);
        q.setString("codeImmeuble", codeImmeuble);
        q.setString("annee", annee);

        proprietaireInt = (ProprietaireInt) q.uniqueResult();
        session.flush();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       System.out.println(e.getMessage()+" "+e.getStackTrace());
    }
    return  proprietaireInt;
}
```

My errror :

> 2010-08-02 12:12:22,081 ERROR
>   ast.ErrorCounter
>   (ErrorCounter.java:33) - line 1:156:
>   unexpected token: proprietaireInt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if JOIN ON is supported (see [HHH-16](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-16) and <strike>[HHH-620](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-620)</strike>) but, assuming `ProprietaireInt` is an entity, I guess the `JOIN` clause should be (note the uppercase first letter):

```
JOIN ProprietaireInt pi ...
```

Also since you're using projections (without a constructor expression), you'll get a `Object[]` as result and I don't think the following will work:

```
proprietaireInt = (ProprietaireInt) q.uniqueResult();
```

From the reference documentation:

> #### [14.6. The select clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select)
>
> ...
>
> Queries can return multiple objects
>   and/or properties as an array of type
>   `Object[]`:
>
> ```
> select mother, offspr, mate.name
> from DomesticCat as mother
>     inner join mother.mate as mate
>     left outer join mother.kittens as offspr
> ```
>
> Or as a `List`:
>
> ```
> select new list(mother, offspr, mate.name)
> from DomesticCat as mother
>     inner join mother.mate as mate
>     left outer join mother.kittens as offspr
> ```
>
> Or - assuming that the class Family
>   has an appropriate constructor - as an
>   actual typesafe Java object:
>
> ```
> select new Family(mother, mate, offspr)
> from DomesticCat as mother
>     join mother.mate as mate
>     left join mother.kittens as offspr
> ```

#### See also

- [14.3. Associations and joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins)
- [14.4. Forms of join syntax](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins-forms)
- [14.6. The select clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select)